# How to set a default value in a text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I know this question has been asked a zillion times, but I still feel I'm missing something obvious. Given a model `Address` with a field `city` which we want to be initialized with a default value, say `Awesome City`.

What I've tried so far:

1) Default value in the view:

```
# @file: /app/views/addresses/_form.html.erb
<dt><%= f.label :city %></dt>
<dd><%= f.text_field :city, :value => 'Awesome city' %></dd>
```

This works but doesn't feel right. Also the user cannot change it, the value will still be `Awesome city`.

2) Overwriting the `city` method:

```
# @file: app/models/address.rb
def city
  self[:city] ||= 'Awesome city'
end
```

The field is rendered empty, so for some reason it doesn't work. If you try `Address.new.city` you get the default value though.

3) Assign the default value in the controller:

```
# address doesn't have a controller, we use nested forms
# belongs_to :parent
# @file: /app/controllers/parents_controller.rb
def new
  @parent = Parent.new
  @parent.build_address 
  @parent.address.city = 'Awesome city'
end
```

This actually works but I don't think it should be in the controller, rather in the model.

4) Adding an `after_initialize` call (yes, it works, you don't have to overwrite the callback):

```
# @file: app/models/address.rb
after_initialize :set_default_city
def set_default_city
   self.city = 'Awesome city'
end
```

This works as well, but this will be called every time an object is instantiated as well, which we don't want.

5) JavaScript, this seems like an extreme measure, it should be easier than this.

Bottom line: what's the best way to add a default value? Everytime I have to give a field a default value it seems I'm trying to hard for such a simple thing. Are there other options which I'm missing?

**Edit:**: I'm using Rails 3.1.4 with Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.2

Comment: probly not the right answare to this but one solution would be to use the before_save hook and set the default city

Comment: That would work, but that will not help in showing up a value in the view.

Comment: true, if you don't want to use hook you could always create a factory method that creates your custom instance, like Parent.make_custom(options)

Comment: Another option that I didn't think about it. Can you add it as an answer and a bit more detailed, with some sample code maybe? I think it's an option to be considered, just like @gabrielhilal with migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it in your migration file:

```
class CreateAddress < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      ...
      t.string :city, default: "Awesome City"
      ...

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Other option is to define it in the `new` action, in your controller, which is more flexible... So, when you create a new `address` it will be started with the default value....

```
 def new
   @address = Address.new
   @address.city ||= "Awesome City"
   ...
 end
```

**EDIT** - possible solution to define default value in the model:

```
before_save :set_default_city
def set_default_city
   self.city ||= 'Awesome city'
end
```

Comment: I've already covered the case with default value in the controller. But I don't think it's the best approach. I'll try the migration one.

Comment: The migration works, grant you point for that. But not very flexible like you mention as well. So I guess the controller approach seems to be the most flexible/easy to use so far. But my instincts tell me this should be the job of the model, not the controller to set up defaults.

Comment: I saw your edited question... what if your use `before_save` instead of `after_initialize`. I will edit my answer.. I haven't tested yet, but you can try it.

Comment: So, the problem is not making sure that a value gets saved in the database. For that kind of situation your solution with the migration would be the best approach. I need one, where I have a default value in the view as well. Before save callbacks will get called too late for that. `after_initialize` is the only one but that one is too expensive and cannot be called only on some actions (only on create for example).

Comment: OK, decided that migration is the best way. Thank you and all for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

My ruby is a little rusty but something like

```
Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.custom_parent(options)
    custom_parent = self.new
    if options.empty?
      custom_parent.update_attributes(default_options)
    else
      //Iterate over all options and assign them to custom_parent
    end

    return custom_parent
  end
end
```

you have to create the "default_options" hash

I don't think this will run out of the box but I think you got my thought